# c++ library to make tar files

Tags: c++, tar

Is there any c++ library available which can create tar files ? I have stream of text which I need to break into parts and make small files which should all reside in a tar ball !

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick Google search uncovers the **[Chilkat C/C++ TAR Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/tar-c++.asp)**. A sample of its use is available here: [Chilkat C++ Examples: Create TAR Archive](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/tar_create.asp)

Another possible option is [libtar](https://github.com/tklauser/libtar) (note, however, that it is a C library).

And, of course, you could read the TAR file spec (all of what you need is linked through [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format))) and implement your own library. It looks like someone has already done that [here](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-tar-file-in-c.html), with the source available.

Comment: The library in the "here" link worked surprising well for me:
http://plindenbaum.blogspot.ca/2010/08/creating-tar-file-in-c.html

Comment: It seems like [`libarchive`](It seems like `libarchive` is ) is actively maintained (in contrast to `libtar`) and much more feature rich. Also, main linux distros seem to ship it in their standard repositories.

Comment: Here is a good free alternative for creation of tarballs only: https://github.com/Armchair-Software/tar_to_stream

Answer (score 6):

[libtar](http://freecode.com/projects/libtar) has a C API for GNU tar.

Comment: Hi Wil.. are there any tutorials to use this library? also i need to use it for a 64 bit program on windows. Do the standard UNIX libtar work well on windows too?

Comment: LibTar can actually be found at http://www.destructor.de/libtar/ and http://www.destructor.de/libtar/. The link of wilhelm tell doesn't exist actually.

Comment: I believe the correct link should be [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/) which appears to be down at the moment.