# Can zlib create tar file, on Windows?

Tags: windows, compression, gzip, tar, zlib

Have zlib for Visual Studio on windows.

Can I create a tar compressed file?

If so, what is the proper file extension for a tar file compressed with zlib.

(I see that gzip can do this and has the .tgz extension, does zlib contain gzip?)

Comment: You'll need something besides/beyond zlib for tar format.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812837/c-library-to-make-tar-files

Comment: @rhashimoto: is this addition used with zlib or completely different?

Comment: It depends on what tar library you use.  Some of them include compression and some don't (because a compressed tar file is just a regular tar file fed through a gzip or bzip compressor).  You'll have to check the details of the library you select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip and zlib are used for compression. The tar archiving functionality is not provided by them. For creating a .tgz file, you typically use tar with `czf` flags, which then uses gzip for compression. If you need tar functionality, [libarchive](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm) looks good for the job.

Comment: .: where do you use the czf flags? in which utility?

Comment: I mean use something like `tar czf archive.tgz file1 file2 file3`.