# how do I decompress tar.gz file using c++ program

Tags: c++

In my linux program, I want to decompress a tar.gz file contents to a specific directory. Is there any system call or any C++ class available in C/C++ to extract file contents from tar.gz file?

Comment: [tar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812837/c-library-to-make-tar-files) and [gz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624250/how-do-i-read-write-gzipped-files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a .gz file line-by-line in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201538/how-to-read-a-gz-file-line-by-line-in-c)

Comment: @bobah: this is not a duplicate. linked question talks about single .gz file, while this one is about .tar.gz archive with many files in it

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 14):

There is excellent library **[libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/)**, which supports accessing multiple archive formats using consistent API. You can follow **[these examples](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples)** on how to use it.

If you are on Ubuntu, you can easily install this library using command `sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev`. On other platforms, you may need to download source code and compile this library yourself.

One advantage of using libarchive vs. using `system()` calls is not depending on system utilities, and also it should work faster because it does not fork.

Comment: libarchive is for c  not c++.

Comment: @user60627: what stops you from using C library in C++ program?

Comment: error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions.

I used codeblocks and only works in c .

Comment: no, I am trying to find any tutorial about it. I never use wrapper before. THX.

Comment: On Ubuntu it's `sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev`

Comment: libarchive unpacks unicode paths incorrectly on Windows! Please do not recommend this library as a universal solution. It is a good Linux library, but it is a big trap for people who write multiplatform applications on Linux.

Comment: @Clare, instead of complaining, perhaps you should consider submitting a patch to fix libarchive file path handling - it's how open source works.

Answer (score -5):

You can use several libs like libtar.

Or you can use a system call like you already mentioned:

```
system("tar -zxf /your/file.tar.gz")
```